# Call the controller method using Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a controller's method by using ajax but somehow I am unable to call the method. I am sending an array type object as a parameter to post but not getting the value of the parameter on the controller, Even I send the parameter as `JSON.stringify` but the problem still exists.

**Here is my ajax method.**

```js
$('.btn-generate-bill').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const billArray = [];
  $('.posTable').find('tbody tr').each(function(index, elem) {
    billArray.push({
      ProductID: $(elem).find('.productID').text().trim(),
      Quantity: $(elem).find('.qtyControl').val()
    });
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(billArray));
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Cashier/UpdateProductQuantity",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      pDetail: JSON.stringify(billArray)
    },
    responseType: "json",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true,
    async: false,
    processData: true,
    success: function(data) {
      alert('success');
    }
  });
})
```

Here is the controller's method.

```
public JsonResult UpdateProductQuantity(List<Test> pDetail)
{
    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class Test
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a GET request for modification?  This should be a PATCH

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: `async: false` has been deprecated for quite a while; it's time to stop using it.

Comment: ok will be careful next time

Comment: @shamisheikh Is this problem solved?

Comment: @AntoOne Thank you so much for your valuable time the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 points to be fixed :

1. ajax without the type will become a `GET` request. Put `POST`
2. try using data: `JSON.stringify({ 'pDetail': billArray})`

So, it becomes :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Cashier/UpdateProductQuantity",
    type : 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'pDetail': billArray}),
    responseType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Comment: The endpoint only accepts a GET though, so that needs to be edited

Answer (score 1):

I would try FromBody with your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateProductQuantity([FromBody]List<Test> pDetail)
{
    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You said you needed to post your billArray so your ajax request should be a post type like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/Cashier/UpdateProductQuantity",
type : 'POST', //this is the difference
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify({ 'pDetail': billArray}),
responseType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    alert('success');
}
});
```